# difference between new type[0] and null - java

Tags: java, arrays, null

What is the difference between

```
type[] a = new type[0];
```

and

```
type[] a = null;
```

Do either forms occupy any memory ? Are there any similarities / differences ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first one (`new type[0]`) will actually create an array object (and therefore occupy memory). You can use the (0-sized) array object, for example to get its length or iterate over it, but you can, of course, not access any of its elements. So you can pass it to any function that doesn't make assumptions about the array's length (but does the proper checks instead) and it will work.

The second one (`null`) doesn't create any object. You will get an exception, if you try to access any member.

Answer (score -1):

You need 3 steps to create an object.

1. Decleration 
   type A[]; -> A decleration.
   When you declare an object, you do not occupy any memory for the instance but occupy some memory for the reference.
2. Instantiation
   To do this,you need 'new' keyword.
   When you instantiate an object,you do occupy memory.
3. Initialization
   To do this you need constructor,
   Like -> type A[] = new A[size];
   That's it.

Comment: This is not exactly truth. Even a non-assigned variable occupies (may occupy) some memory. Not the memory of the instance, but the memory needed for the reference.

Comment: Of course even non-assigned variable occupies some memory but the question is that i understood whether instance occupies some memory.Sorry, you're right about that.